# ¿Debemos editar la palabra "deployar" y cambiarla por "desplegar"?

Tags: discusión, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, ediciones

Me he encontrado recientemente en una respuesta la palabra "deployar":

https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/70554/revisions

No me he atrevido a editarla por si fuera una palabra tipo array/arreglo donde está muy aceptada según la zona y forma de hablar de cada autor.

Buscando la palabra "deployar" en la barra de búsqueda me he encontrado 18 ocurrencias; por lo que parece que, por lo menos, no es invento del autor de la respuesta.

Lo que me gustaría saber es si esta palabra es comúnmente aceptada o si habría que editarla por otra como "desplegar".

Ya puestos, hay una etiqueta "deployment". ¿Debería ser sinónimo de "despliegue"?

EDIT: Voy a ir recopilando una lista de palabras similares, por si en el futuro se busca sobre alguna palabra parecida, que aparezca este hilo. Si os apetece, poned un comentario con palabras que se os ocurra para que las pueda añadir o directamente editad esta pregunta y añadir la que queráis.

- Array
- Arreglo
- Castear / Casteado
- Chequear(*) / Checado / Chequeado
- Codear / Codeado
- Commitear / Commiteado / Comitear / Comiteado
- Customizar / Customizado
- Default
- Deployar / Deployado
- Debuguear / Debugado / Debugueado
- Deprecar / Deprecado
- Hardcodear / Harcodeo / Hardcodeado
- Jotasonizar / Jotasonizado
- Linkear / Linkar / Linquear / Lincar / Linkado / Lincado / Linqueado / Linkeado
- Parsear / Parseado
- [Performancia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/328775/revisions)
- Pushear / Pusheado
- [Randómico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/330078/cambiar-de-estado-randomico-al-presionar-un-boton-android-studio)
- Setear / Seteado
- Splitear / Spliteado / Esplitear / Espliteado
- Trimear / Trimeado / Trimmear / Trimmeado

(*) Chequear está en el diccionario de la RAE

Comment: de hecho pasa con otras palabras como "setear" , "deprecado", "chequear" , "customizar", y lo peor es que así se esta aprendiendo en la universidad; si es asi tu pregunta deberian tener esto ,que  pasara si en una pregunta cambiamos setear por asignar, deprecar por obsoleto, chequear por verificar, customizar por personalizar , los otros usuarios de revisión pueden interpretar que cambia el contenido

Comment: tambien me dijo un colega, que si esta en la sociedad debemos adaptarnos y no hacer tantas exigencias, pero cuando tu  lo digas dilo bien y explica el porque

Comment: @JackNavaRow hay sabiduría en esas palabras, gracias por sharearlo.

Comment: "castear", "parsear", "debuggear" y otras decenas de palabras que seguramente he usado mal. Como dice @JackNavaRow se acaban aprendiendo de otros compañeros y incluso en clase. En este caso "deployar" ya la había escuchado por lo que no me sorprende. En el caso de que se "deban" de editar creo que vendría bien un diccionario de todas estas palabras con sus correspondientes traducciones.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. En programacion se usan anglicismos todo el tiempo, porque los lenguajes y herramientas estan en ese idioma. ya sabemos que es un array, o que es un varchar, o un string.. no traducimos las palabras del lenguaje, tampoco me parece que debieramos traducir terminos tecnicos asociados a la programación.

Comment: ah, con lo de la etiqueta si que estoy de acuerdo :)

Comment: El traductor de Google me marca una alternativa de la traducción deploy del inglés y en español sería **implementar**.

Comment: Buena esa: *gracias por __sharearlo__...*, XD el mejor comentario.

Comment: Yo estoy completamente de acuerdo @gbianchi, en en mundo de la programacióm (incluso en todo el sector tecnológico) usamos muchísima terminología angosajona que en ocaciones castellanizamos con el objetivo de hacer entender mejor. Esto ocurre porque este sector está dominado por el idioma inglés, por lo que a veces despegarnos de este idioma y traducir la terminología solo trae confisión. Debemos tener en cuenta que, aunque no sea el caso de deploy, hay muchas palabras que no tienen una correspondencia exacta del inglés al castellano (me viene a la cabeza commit).

Comment: otra palabra polemica [default](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=default), este tema se expande mucho!

Comment: por cierto escribe en google translate verificar y llevalo a español y viceversa

Comment: Con respecto a esto pude decir algo que sucedió en mi país, antiguamente la palabra ganar hacia referencia a obtener algo un premio, remuneración, pero mucha gente lo usaba como verbo de posicionarse en algún lugar, como ganate aquí, ganémonos acá y otros, yo siempre hacia la corrección y era mal visto usar ese verbo para posicionarse, lo usaba la gente poco culta e ignorante del lenguaje, pero de tanto usarse la RAE la acepto como tal y ahora tiene los 2 usos, en resumen podemos decir que el lenguaje esta vivo y evoluciona independiente de lo que dicten los convencionalismos, ej: bizarro...

Answer (score 11):

**IMHO**

Sabemos que el término *deployar* no existe en el Castellano. Tampoco existen términos como *setear*, *debuguear*, *castear*. Y como dice @gbianchi (saludos desde mi corazón *Javero* y *Javascriptero* [palabras también inventadas]), [hay muchos anglicismos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4585/debemos-editar-la-palabra-deployar-y-cambiarla-por-desplegar#comment18809_4585) que de una u otra forma ya son parte de nuestro léxico.

Este sitio es sobre **programación** tal como lo establece el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), por lo tanto, si bien se pide que las preguntas y respuestas estén redactadas en castellano (*español* es un gentilicio no un idioma [este comentario intenta demostrar algo]), el sitio no trata sobre la exactitud o buen uso del lenguaje y no me refiero a un lenguaje de programación (ya que de eso sí se trata), sino al lenguaje hablado o escrito de esta versión de StackOverflow.

Por lo tanto, siempre que el OP pueda expresar correctamente sus ideas, independientemente de si usa términos inventados (*deployar*, *setear*, *linkear*, etc.) o anglicismos (*tengo un `Array`*, *cuando hago `click`*, *usando este `Framework`*, etc.) no deberíamos tener problemas a la hora de responder una pregunta.

Comparto la opinión de @JackNavaRow sobre el [*practicar lo que predico*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4585/debemos-editar-la-palabra-deployar-y-cambiarla-por-desplegar#comment18805_4585). Y es que mientras cada uno de nosotros haga su parte por hablar bien el castellano, estaremos enseñando mediante el ejemplo, sin antagonizar ni entrar en la llamada *guerra de ediciones*, porque al fin de cuentas nadie es dueño de la verdad absoluta.

El sitio se llama StackOverflow en Español, y aunque como dije anteriormente *Español* es un gentilicio y no un idioma o lengua, hemos aceptado su uso (sobretodo fuera de España), como el nombre del idioma. Si nos ponemos finos con el uso del lenguaje de la forma en la que se propone, deberíamos cambiarle el nombre al sitio para que sea **StackOverflow en Castellano**.

Así no creo que vayamos a ninguna parte, al contrario pienso que sería un esfuerzo fatuo.

Comment: Setear: llenar de setas.

Answer (score 10):

Si tu pregunta va sobre el uso de la palabra *Deployar* en el sitio, no estoy de acuerdo.

Por las siguientes razones:

- Lo que cuesta que un usuario nuevo escriba una pregunta bien y vamos prácticamente a agregar reglas gramaticales a su pregunta
- Por otro lado modificar la palabra [deployar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deployar) en las preguntas por la palabra traducida al español, no tiene un impacto a gran escala.
- El efecto dominó con otras palabras castellanizadas (por ejemplo [*deprecado*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deprecado))
- Haríamos tan complejo preguntar/responder que nadie lo haría o se lo pensarían mucho.
- El *feedback* negativo que podría percibir el OP debido a la corrección recibida, cuando ambos (tanto el OP como el que corrige) creen estar en lo correcto.
- Nuestro *Meta* se llenaría de preguntas gramaticales y sin sentido con discusiones que no acabarían nunca.

---

**Mi opinión personal**

Si alguien me habla de ["setear"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=setear) en la pregunta, por ejemplo, cuando respondo hablo de "asignar". Si el OP u otro usuario me pregunta porqué lo digo de esa forma, le doy mis razones y la mayoría de las veces concordamos.

¿Cómo podemos decirle a alguien que el uso de un término o palabra está mal cuando en los centros educativos (Institutos, Universidades, etc.) enseñan usando estos términos?.

Tengo un amigo que me preguntó:

- ¿Dime cómo dirías en español ["castear"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=castear) y que cuando se lo digas a otros desarrolladores comprendan lo que quieres decir?.

(Pensé en "moldear" pero obviamente no comprenderían)

Comment: guerra de ediciones entre array, vector y arreglo!!!!!

Comment: @gbianchi Ahí yo prefiero que si está en array, se quede en array, arreglo suena mal, no están reparando nada, vector suena bien. Yo no cambiaría esa palabra, aunque cambiaría matrix por matriz.

Comment: "*vamos prácticamente a agregar reglas gramaticales a su pregunta*" no vamos a agregarlas, ya existen: "*Bamos haver, si aljien redakta azí te parezeria vien??'''*".

Comment: "*¿Cómo podemos decirle a alguien que el uso de un término o palabra está mal cuando en los centros educativos (Institutos, Universidades, etc.) enseñan usando estos términos?*" Que en los centros educativos enseñen mal, no es excusa para enseñar mal fuera de ellos.

Comment: @gbianchi Ojo: quienes recién inician en C++ e hijos deben decir array y quienes les enseñan procurar que no lo vean ni remotamente similar a vector. El **container** vector no es ni remotamente afín a los vectores de Erre ene que se malusan para ofrecer representaciones elementales de los **arreglos**.
Digo todo esto para insistir en la idea: Cuando hablamos de lenguajes de programación debemos tratar de mantener las locuciones lo más cerca posible de sus originales anglófonas para evitar cargarlas de falsos significados provenientes del Español (porque Castellano también es un gentilicio).

Answer (score 6):

> ¿Debemos editar la palabra “deployar” y cambiarla por “desplegar”?

Si.

---

Es una queja recurrente (al menos en mi círculo) que no existe documentación sobre programación en nuestro idioma. Los motivos de esta carencia dan para otro debate y se han hablado anteriormente (al menos en [el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)) pero sean cuales sean esos motivos, la solución es generar documentación en nuestro idioma.

Si empezamos a redactar documentación sobre programación en *spanglish* o *engañol* no aportaremos una solución al problema si no que lo haremos más complejo; no veo motivo por el que debamos luchar contra un idioma consolidado, con reglas ya establecidas y hablado por varios millones de personas para inventar un idioma nuevo surgido del caos, que miles de programadores deberán aprender de nuevo.

Comment: Paper siempre admiro la forma diferente que vez las cosas, el problema en este caso no es con esa palabra sino el efecto domino que traera

Comment: Lo se @JackNavaRow pero no puedes hacer una tortilla si no rompes algunos huevos.

Answer (score 6):

El tema en sí es complicado; la carrera que llevamos sobre tecnología, la programación y derivados tiene alto uso de términos de lengua inglesa, el problema es: ¿Qué tanto rompemos un idioma para llevarlo a otro?

En este post trataré en lo posible ir de una idea central, a una visión macro para tener un panorama general y finalmente ir a una visión micro para darle forma a esta situación.

Me explico:

**La distorsión de palabras extranjeras**

El "espanglish" tiene su lado práctico y su lado crítico, un ejemplo: "mi waifa está suipeando la yarda y luego va para la marketa". Que se entiende, creo que sí se entiende, que suena raro, definitivamente (opinión personal). Sobre este ejemplo, hay quienes lo aceptan, quienes lo rechazan, quienes lo usan y quienes jamás en su vida piensan en hacer uso de ello así tengan la oportunidad.

La pregunta es: ¿Está bien usar un idioma mezclado/distorcionado con otro a ese nivel? ¿Está mal? Esto es relativo dependiendo del lugar donde se viva y el uso que la sociedad le asigne.

Un poco de historia sobre el origen de los idiomas y su evolución con el paso del tiempo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMi5vduNWtI

Del Latin se derivaron varias lenguas, ¿por qué? Por el uso de la sociedad. Podemos revisar más detalles en https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_romances

Ahora que ya tenemos el panorama general, vamos viajando a lo más centrado.

**La adaptación de palabras extranjeras**

Las palabras: **café, taxi** son usadas y aceptadas sin problemas en varias partes del mundo. Hace poco vi una publicación de un usuario en twitter diciendo que iba a hacer "carpool" a lo que algunos saltaron, en mi Perú, le llamamos "taxi colectivo", o sencillamente "colectivo", estoy acostumbrado a escuchar la palabra "carpool" y pues, me dio igual, en este ejemplo nótese el contexto "la costumbre". El problema que podría desarrollarse de este caso: escriban la palabra "carpul" que está ausente en español, y en inglés...

**¿Estamos evolucionando/distorcionando el lenguaje informático?**

Me parece que esta es la pregunta elemental a resolver, hay palabras que sí encajan bien usadas correctamente en el idioma original (inglés en este caso), nada rompen puesto que la integración es suave (smooth), sin embargo hay otras que... cuestan procesar, dado que sí existen palabras en español para ellas, veamos la siguiente lista:

```
Se "comitea" el código y va para la "master branch".
Se "envía" el código y va para la "rama maestra".
Vamos a debuggear el código.
Vamos a desinsectizar el código. //Aquí suena a que vas a ir por un baygon/raid max
Tengo que darle un casteo a una variable.
Tengo que transformar una variable.
El casting de la variable ha fallado.
La transformación de la variable ha fallado.
Tienes que castear la variable.
Tienes que transformar la variable.
El Array genera undefined.
El Arreglo genera undefined.
El Vector genera undefined.
Hay que customizar el componente.
Hay que personalizar el componente.
Ese comportamiento está by default.
Ese comportamiento está por default.
Ese comportamiento está por defecto.
El proyecto se ha deployado.
El proyecto se ha desplegado.
El proyecto se ha implementado.
Vamos a tener que codear a todo dar.
Vamos a tener que programar a todo dar.
El componente ha sido codeado en <inserte lenguaje que no programarías>, no lloren.
El componente ha sido programado en <inserte lenguaje que no programarías>, no lloren.
//El siguiente ejemplo tuve que leer repetidas veces para entender, a la primera no entendí.
Ese procedimiento va a jotasonizar la clase.
//Mi compilador español-inglés-inglés-español acaba de "crashear". 
Ese procedimiento genera una clase jotasonizada.
Esa parte del sistema está hardcodeada.
Esa parte del sistema tiene "código duro".
Esa funcionalidad está deprecada.
Esa funcionalidad está quedando obsoleta.
Vas a tener que parsear ese texto a json. //¡Saludos parce!
```

Como podemos ver, hay palabras que usando tal cual en el inglés se mantiene la armonía gramatical (espero me deje entender con estas dos palabras). La españolización forzada la destruye...

> ¿Debemos editar la palabra “deployar” y cambiarla por “desplegar”?

Sí, por favor. El motivo es simple: tiene una palabra existente en el español.

---

Un último punto: Pensemos que persona está aprendiendo a programar y habla un idioma ajeno al español e inglés y que por alguna razón le ha dado ganas de aprender español orientado a la programación y llega a nuestro sitio de SOes, ¿se le hará fácil entender terminos como `jotazonisar`, `deployar` usando traductores online? Venga que la globalización es un hecho.

¿Les parece si hacemos el esfuerzo en mantener el español lo más limpio posible y lo mismo para términos en inglés? Gracias por su atención y paciencia para leer todo el contenido de esta respuesta, que tengan un bonito día :D

Comment: si a casi todo, pero desplegar por deployar no te la compro... :p

Comment: Muy fino y juicioso razonamiento. Y, dices bien dónde hay equivalencia, i.e. existe la palabra o una frase en español, usémosle; pero cuando la equivalencia es forzada o tristemente insuficiente, adaptemos las locuciones al caso.

Comment: @gbianchi no te vendo, te la regalo :v dale hermano, ponele voluntad :D

Comment: "*Debuggar*" ⇒ "*Depurar*", "*Hardcodeado*" ⇒ "*Incrustado*".

Comment: La palabra depurar está perfecta, código "incrustado", es la primera vez que la leo, ojalá más desarrolladores traten de mantener puros a los idiomas :D

Comment: XD: *¡Saludos parce!*. Usted dijo: *jotasonizar*  ¿Y cómo es eso? Explique pues  parcero.

Comment: A ver parcero (00). Esa misma frase rompió mi compilador de inglés - español, español - inglés. Hasta que vi "jotason" => "jota" = "J" + "Son". Según el contexto, es darle un ".ToJSON"

Comment: @fredyfx Es imposible que sea la primera vez que lees *incrustado*. Supongo que es la primera vez que lees ese uso… sin embargo está mencionado así en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_code) y creo que refleja bien la idea de "*una sección de código que se espera que sea configurable pero está escrito de manera expícita*".

Comment: @MauricioContreras en Inglés yo leo JSON como [Jason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason) (pronunciado *Yeison*) en Español lo leo como [Jasón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasón).

Comment: en efecto mi estimado @PaperBirdMaster, primera vez que veo dicha palabra en ese uso a modo de equivalencia de "hardcoded". Con respecto a lo otro, suena como título de película: Jason y los argonautas :v

Comment: "Por el Poder de GreySQUL, yo te jotazoniso"

jotazonisar, esa palabra has de patentarla, y en mi mente suena "jota-son" cuando leo JSON

Comment: HAHAAAAAA XD!!! eso fue demasiado gráfico hahahaa xD!!!. "Yo te Jotasonizo", esto merece un premio a la creatividad xD!!!!

Answer (score 4):

El termino "deployar" no existe en el castellano, pienso que para una mejor compresión se debería de cambiar por "desplegar".

Y si, estoy de acuerdo en que "deployment" debería ser sinonimo de "despliegue", al ser un foro hispano debemos de intentar no usar anglicismos para que todo el mundo pueda entenderlo todo.

Comment: y para entrar en una eterna discusion, aca hacemos deploy, no hacemos despliegues :(

Comment: Entenderia el uso de la palabra deploy, pero no entiendo su españolización, al usar deployar estamos denigrando nuestra lengua, no tiene nada de malo usar la palabra despliegue

Comment: no, pero no se que vas a desplegar.. una vela? una cartulina? ojo, recuerden que no todos hablamos el mismo español!!! ojo con traducir a un español en particulr....

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero como muchas palabras en nuestro idioma, desplegar puede tener muchos significados, y al usarla en este foro, estamos en un contexto en el que solo puede significar una cosa, no daría lugar a ninguna confusión.

Comment: no necesariamente.. un usuario novato podria no entender que desplegar es la trauduccion de deploy....

Comment: ¿Y "deployar" que es una palabra inventada si lo va a entender?, si un usuario no entiende una palabra lo normal es que se documente, al poco de buscar encontrará lo que significa, igualmente no todas las personas hablan inglés y entiende a lo que se refiere "deploy"

Comment: Y así son los debates interminables, en una parte del mundo es aceptado usar una palabra que no existe en castellano: *deployar*. Y la traducción al castellano de *deploy* es *despliegue*. @gbianchi pregunta: *pero no se que vas a desplegar.. una vela? una cartulina?* y es que precisamente ese es el significado de *deploy* en inglés, no sólo es para hacer *software deployment*:  [*deploy*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deploy). Por lo tanto no es traído de los pelos decir: *desplegar una aplicación o software*, IMHO.

Comment: No he visto de mis amigos programadores decir ya jale los cambios y empuje a la rama maestra xD

Comment: Considero, que en la medida de lo posible se debe evitar el uso de palabras en inglés, a menos que no se pueda evitar. Para ese caso, deberían utilizarse algo parecido a esto: _desplegar (deploy)_ o por ejemplo, _despligue (deployment)_. Esto no solo ayudará a las personas que ya son programadores a mejorar el idioma, también ayudarán a las personas que quieren iniciarse en este mundo a entender lo que decimos.

Comment: Cuenta en pocas palabras que pasa con tu software cuando haces deploy del mismo. Luego en otro párrafo cuenta que lo desplegaste. Finalmente entrega los dos textos a varias personas y has recuento de cuantos entendieron lo mismo al leer los dos párrafos. Si la frecuencia relativa de aciertos es alta, me rendiré ante la evidencia fáctica y apoyaré de modo irrestricto que se haga traducción. De otra forma, me mantendré en que esos términos deben mantener dicción cercana a su original y "españolizarse"

Answer (score 3):

Todas las entradas de la lista tienen equivalente en español, en ocasiones más de una.
Siempre he pensado que los informáticos hablamos (me incluyo) un spanglish propio por no molestarnos en usar un diccionario ingles-español. Una solución sencilla no implementada en las cabezas de muchos.
Todas las traducciones las he sacado del [Glosario de Terminología Informática del Tugurium](http://www.tugurium.com/gti)

Array
Arreglo

> cadena, vector, matriz, fila, hilera

Castear / Casteado

> moldeado

Chequear(*) / Checado / Chequeado

> control, verificación, comprobación

Codear / Codeado

> codificar

Commitear / Commiteado / Comitear / Comiteado

> confirmar, acometer, ejecutar

Customizar / Customizado

> personalizar, ajustar, adaptar

Default

> predeterminado, por omisión, por defecto

Deployar / Deployado

> desplegar

Debuguear / Debugado / Debugueado

> depurar

Deprecar / Deprecado

> desaconsejado, obsoleto

Hardcodear / Harcodeo / Hardcodeado

> incrustado en el código, fijo -

Jotasonizar / Jotasonizado

> json (hace referencia a una sigla, desplegado sería: Notación de Objetos en JavaScript)

Linkear / Linkar / Linquear / Lincar / Linkado / Lincado / Linqueado / Linkeado

> enlazar, montar, unir, ligar

Parsear / Parseado

> análisis sintáctico, análisis, reconocimiento, descomposición

Performancia

> prestación, rendimiento

Pushear / Pusheado

> introducir, insertar, cargar

Setear / Seteado

> asignar, activar, establecer, inicializar

Splitear / Spliteado / Esplitear / Espliteado

> dividir, separar, partir

Trimear / Trimeado / Trimmear / Trimmeado

> compensador, ajustador, corrector

Comment: Lo primero, gracias por el enlace, es una referencia muy buena para este tipo de términos. Por otra parte, aunque haya una palabra equivalente en castellano, ¿realmente nos ayuda a comunicarnos? Si a un compañero le pregunto si ha "trimeado" una cadena, creo que me va a entender mejor que si le pregunto si ha "compensado", "ajustado" o "corregido" una cadena. Tendría que darle explicaciones adicionales, cuando el término "trimear" no existe pero transmite mejor lo que le estoy preguntando. Otra opción sería dar un rodeo y decir: ¿has aplicado la función `trim` a la cadena?

Comment: Cuando entré en contacto con los computadores (1971) se oían barbarismos como: ¿has sorteado el archivo? Seguro que lo entiendes, ahora bien ¿no es mejor hablar de 'ordenar'? Hoy nadie habla de sort -> sortear, porque se ha ido normalizando el lenguaje, y eso, aquí, depende de nosotros los informáticos. Así, eliminar espacios de una cadena puede ser 'aplicar la función trim' o 'ajustar la cadena'. La comunicación depende del que habla y donde lo habla, e inventarnos palabras todos los días, cuando las hay, me parece una vía para confundirnos más que para entendernos.

Answer (score 2):

Fácil, si queremos un sitio serio con documentos de calidad, no debemos admitir palabras incorrectas.
Una cosa es usar palabras en inglés, y otra traducirlo como queramos, como con "arreglo", traducción fonética de "array".
Resumiendo, no deberíamos admitir palabras que no se usen en documentaciones oficiales.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, se debe admitir el uso de palabras en ingles pero no inventadas o "castellanisadas", la palabra deployar no existe ni en el español ni en el ingles, en español sería desplegar y si se va a usar convinado con el ingles se debería a comodar en la frase como "...realice un deploy del proyecto..." o "..haré un deploy..."